# How to access JSON object 'key' dynamically without using [key]?

Tags: javascript, json, object

For example, my json object is:

```
var obj = {
  a:'aerereasr',
  b:'xxxxxx',
  cc:12345
}
```

let say, if I want to dynamically access or change the value of each key, I normally do this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  obj[key] = 'new value';
}
```

is there alternative way for `obj[key]`?

Comment: Why can't you use [key]? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `obj.key` but you'd have to hard-code the key name. Other than that, no.

Comment: The problem is that... in mongoose, doc[key] = 'new value'  won't get saved.... but if I explicitly do doc.a = 'new value' it works.

Comment: i do hasOwnProperty. i just abbreviate in the example. :)

Comment: @murvinlai What do you mean by "won't get saved" ?

Comment: @murvinlai Sorry I missed your mention of "mongoose," not familiar with that software.

Comment: Also that is not a JSON object. It would fail validation.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not without using `eval()` or something that invokes `eval()` like interpretation.